# Spring Boot health check for Spring Data Solr

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I'm now using Spring Boot, there's a health check problem.

I have multi-core using spring data solr, so the solr url is the base url, e.g. http://localhost:8983/solr, but the health check will call HttpSolrClient's ping method, which will return a 404 error, how can I do the health check for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with solr..

In Spring Boot version `1.5.9.RELEASE` Solr health check works fine.
Now Healthcheck ping endpoint `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores` so he check Solr serwer health instead at single core as it was before.

If is possible try update your spring boot version.

Answer (score 0):

```
SolrPing solrPing = new SolrPing(); //infoCollection
SolrPingResponse solrPingResponse =  solrPing.process(solrClient,infoCollection);
String status = (String) solrPingResponse.getResponse().get("status");
```

Answer (score -1):

I Believe you can change the Management Port in application.properties which will divert your Management calls from hosted on 8983 port.